# RETURNING value from SELECT table in INSERT .. SELECT

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| column | def  |
| ------ | ---- |
| id     | uuid |
| status | int  |
| data   | text |
```

I'd like to write a query to duplicate a row (changing only a few columns) and return the old (replaced) data:

```
INSERT INTO tmp (status, data)
SELECT source.status, :data
FROM table AS source
WHERE id = :id
RETURNING id, source.data
```

but `RETURNING` can only access values from the inserted row, is there an alternative to do this?

Comment: Can you do it in two passes, or does it have to be in one pass?

Comment: Very similar question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29256888/939860

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can 'store' your old data in a CTE, then do the change in another (writable) CTE, and return the original values like this:

```
WITH old AS (
    SELECT status, data
      FROM your_table
     WHERE id = :id 
),
new AS (
    INSERT INTO your_table
    SELECT status, :data
      FROM old
)
SELECT * FROM old;
```

The writable CTE (`new`) works on the results of the previous one (`old`).

Comment: thx this lead me in the right direction. I just had to SELECT new.id, new.status, old.status FROM old, new